# Восстановить загрузчик Ubuntu

Tags: linux, grub

[image: вывод команды fdisk -l]

Как восстановить загрузчик системного raid 0 ?

root @ ubuntu-mate: / boot File Edit View Search Terminal Help Disk / dev / sda: 149.1 GiV, 160041885696 bytes 312581808 sectors Units: sectors of 1 512 512 bytes Sector size (logtcal / phystcal): 512 bytes 512 bytes I / O size (nninum / optimal): 512 bytes 512 bytes Dtsklabel type: dos Disk identifier: 0x00000000 Device End Sectors stze Id Type Boot start / dev / sda1 1 937731071 93773107 447 .16 ee GPT Disk / dev / sdb: 149.1 G18 169041885696 bytes 312581808 sectors Units: sectors of 1 512 512 bytes Sector size (logtcal / phystcal): 512 bytes 512 bytes I / O size: 512 bytes bytes Dtsklabel type: dos Dtsk tdentifier: 0x26876634 Device Boot start End Sectors Size Id Type / dev / sdb1 0 595967 595968 1M Empty 575836 583923 8088 4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32) / dev / sdb2 Disk / dev / sdc: 149 1 GiV, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors Units: sectors of 1 512 512 bytes Sector size (logical physical): 512 bytes 512 bytes I / 0 size (minimum optimal): 512 bytes 512 bytes Dtsklabel type: dos Disk id entifier 6xod9fod9e Device End Sectors stze Id Type Boot start / dev / sdc1 63 312576704 31 257664 1496 7 HPFS / NTFS / exFA Disk / dev / napper / t sw bbi aifsbb Volume 1: 447.1 GiB, 4801 1838886 4 bytes, 937731072 sectors Units: sectors of 1 512 512 bytes Sector size (logical physical): 512 bytes 512 bytes I / O size (ntntnun / optimal): 32768 bytes 98304 bytes Disk label type: gpt Disk identifier: FEAF5992-4DC0-4CSA-B04A-AA9AB24ASbb Device End Se Start ctors Size Type / dev / mapper / tsw bbtatfacbb_Volune 1-parti 192 1050815 10 50624 513M EFI S / dev / mapper / 1sw_bbtatfacbb_Volune1-part2 1050816 904406207 9033

Comment: А можно текст не в винде скриншота? Я конечно понимаю, что мода, но всё же.

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите Live-CD, с которого Вы ставили систему и загрузитесь с него. Там в меню есть пункт - восстановление загрузчика.